# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added

Tags: android, fragment

My MainActivity's `onStart()` throws `IllegalStateException` with 'Fragment Already Added' message. What am i doing wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ServiceConnection {

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }
}
```

Following is exception stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxx/com.xxx.MainActivity}:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: cj{38f8de4c #0 id=0x7f0b0079 cj}
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3190)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3300)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:211)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1705)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: cj{38f8de4c #0 id=0x7f0b0079 cj}
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1366)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:734)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1682)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:607)
    at com.xxx.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:692)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1264)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6613)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3153)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3300) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:211) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1705) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: please add some more explanation of the problem and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: error says that your fragment is added twice. You shouldn't do that obviously.

Answer (score 2):

You need check if fragment is already exists in transaction or not before replacing or adding fragment to transaction, you can take help from following code:

```
      public void setFragmentToContainer(Fragment fragment)
        {
            final String tag = fragment.getClass().getName();
            if (manager == null) {
                manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            }
            if (isFragmentInBackstack(manager,tag)) {
                // Fragment exists, go back to that fragment
                //// you can also use POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE flag, depending on flow
                manager.popBackStackImmediate(tag, 0);

            } else {
                // Fragment doesn't exist
                // STEP 1 + additional backstack management
            }

            transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.layout_content, fragment);
            if(fragment instanceof CompanyLevelFragment)
            {
                //Exit app on back press
            }else {
                transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
            }
            transaction.commit();


        }

// isFragmentInBackstack method

  public static boolean isFragmentInBackstack(final FragmentManager fragmentManager, final String fragmentTagName) {
        for (int entry = 0; entry < fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount(); entry++) {
            if (fragmentTagName.equals(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(entry).getName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: method of you isFragmentInBackstack ?

Comment: Sorry dont understand @NPBA

Comment: Yes This method will allow you to keep specific fragments on backstack , This method will check if fragment is  already added in Fragment then do popbackstackimmediate with the help of given tag. You have to handle backstack then your problem will get automatically solved

Comment: Please check for you method below

Comment: @NPBA-Get Code for isFragmentInBackstack() method

Comment: Why not using `findFragmentByTag()` instead of `isFragmentInBackstack()`?

Answer (score 2):

### Method replace fragment

```
public boolean replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        String loadingFragment = fragment.getClass().getName();
        if (fragment.getArguments() != null && fragment.getArguments().containsKey(Constant.FRAGMENT_ID)) {
            loadingFragment += fragment.getArguments().getString(Constant.FRAGMENT_ID);
        }
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = MainActivity.getInstance().getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment existedFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(loadingFragment);

        if (existedFragment != null) {
            if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1 || existedFragment.isAdded()) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        try {
            fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_fragment, fragment, loadingFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(loadingFragment);
            //Add fix bug java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

            if(!isFinishing()) {
                fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
            }
            else {
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException ignored) {
            LogHelper.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException ignored ", ignored.getMessage());
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Please add this in question section

Comment: fragment.getClass().getName() something return "cj" It is not my desired results

Comment: Why do you add with `commit()` in a branch `isFinishing()`? I mean, in `if(!isFinishing()) {` you call `commitAllowingStateLoss()`, but in `else` branch call `commit()`. If I don't mind, that will lead to `Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a quick check:

```
    if(myFragment.isAdded()){
       return;
    }
// else continue with code
```

Answer (score 1):

i used Reena solution but i modified it for backstacks as sometimes you do not want to the current fragment to the back stack.  Reena gave a good solution it should have more votes.

```
public void setFragmentToContainer(Fragment fragment,boolean adddToBackStack)
{
    final String tag = fragment.getClass().getName();

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (isFragmentInBackstack(manager,tag)) {
        // Fragment exists, go back to that fragment
        manager.popBackStackImmediate(tag, 0);

    } else {
        // Fragment doesn't exist

        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fl_cart_detail_host_layout, fragment);
       if(adddToBackStack) transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
        transaction.commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not using `findFragmentByTag()` instead of `isFragmentInBackstack()`?

Comment: As I understood you, you don't want to add a fragment if you already have it. Instead you remove upper fragments.